# How to fit linear regression for the whole class?

Tags: python, class, oop, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am getting the following error when I am trying to execute the code below. I understand what it means, but don't know how to solve it.

```
NotFittedError: This LinearRegression instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

The original code:

```
class models:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lm = LinearRegression()
        self.xgb = xgb.XGBRegressor()

    def train_lr(self, X, y, title):
        self.lm.fit(X, y)
        y_hat =  pd.DataFrame(self.lm.predict(X))
        mse = metrics.mean_squared_error(y, y_hat)        
        print('{} set'.format(title))
        print('R2 {}:'.format(title), self.lm.score(X, y))
        print('RMSE {}:'.format(title), math.sqrt(mse))
        print('')
        return self.lm.fit(X, y)
      
    def test_lr(self, X, y, title):
        y_hat =  pd.DataFrame(self.lm.predict(X))
        mse = metrics.mean_squared_error(y, y_hat)        
        print('{} set'.format(title))
        print('R2 {}:'.format(title), self.lm.score(X, y))
        print('RMSE {}:'.format(title), math.sqrt(mse))
        print('')
```

call functions:

```
models().train_lr(X_train, y_train, 'Base line')
models().test_lr(X_test, y_test, 'Base line')
```

Comment: Because you did not instantiate an object and you are calling `train_lr` as an unbound method, you also need to provide something for the first positional argument `self`. You probably want `models().train_lr(X_train, y_train, 'Base line')` instead.

Comment: Am I not puting self.lm for the self argumante?

What would I need to alter to be able to write models, instade of models()?

Comment: According to your code, `models()` is an object of class `models`. If you want to leverage OOP, you should instantiate an object. Otherwise, you may as well just define your `models.train_lr` as a normal function. However, if you insist, you may get around this by either using one of `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod` decorators, or using a meta class. But I doubt any of those is what you want.

Comment: I think you should study OOP a lot more, what you are asking is how to do it the non-OOP way.

Comment: All you have to do is create an instance (object) of the parent class `models`, say `m1 = models()`, then you can use the methods (functions) of class `models` by the following: `m1.train_lr(X_train, y_train, 'Base line')`.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I compleately agree, that's what I am doing. :)

Comment: Please, could you take a look at the updated post? Please could you share examples of code, it si very hard for me to understand just from the description.